# Displaying a text box

Tags: c#, textbox, arcmap, arcobjects

I've searched the questions for an answer but couldn't quite find a clear cut example. I am trying to display a simple text box in C#. I am working with C#, ArcMap and ArcObjects. I have created a toolbar that has a button in it. Upon clicking the button, I just need a text box to appear on the page. So far, this is what I've got, but nothing is producing when I click my button. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Map
{
    public class ArcGISAddin4 : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        public ArcGISAddin4()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
            dynamicTextBox.Text = "My First Text Box";
            dynamicTextBox.Name = "First Text Box";
            dynamicTextBox.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you said that **just need a text box to appear on the page**; which **page** do you refer to?

Comment: Well since I'm in ArcMap, I would load an mxd (map document) to the page. I would need the text box to appear on top of the mxd.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the TextBox to the surrounding container (the form for example). Otherwise the program won't know where it's supposed to be displayed.

Comment: There is no natural "form" per say. There is an mxd (map document) that is loaded into ArcMap that I need the text box to display on the map document. But I guess I should consider the mad document to be the "form". I will give this a try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `dynamicTextBox` to a specific container such as form.
Such as this:

```
 TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
 dynamicTextBox.Text = "My First Text Box";
 dynamicTextBox.Name = "First Text Box";
 dynamicTextBox.Enabled = true;
 this.Contols.Add(dynamicTextBox);//this is a pseudo code
```

Comment: `this.Contols.Add(dynamicTextBox);` would probably be better since I doubt the OP is referring to his current object in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will give it a shot though and continue testing.

Comment: I can't enter in the code --> this.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox); ...I get an error saying that there is no definition for 'Controls' and no extension method...... Of course this is accurate, but I am not using a typical form. I guess you can't just display a textbox on an mxd through this way.